# display future posts in date page

Tags: date, calendar

hey im trying to display future posts in date page but date page redirect to 404 page when it is future date so i used this function

```
function dg_override_404() {
    global $wp_query, $post;
    if(is_year() || is_day()){
        $wp_query->is_404 = true;
    }
    if($wp_query->post_count == 0){
        $dayarchive = get_query_var('day');
        $monthnumarchive = get_query_var( 'monthnum' );
        $yeararchive = get_query_var( 'year' );
        if ( $dayarchive || $monthnumarchive){
            status_header( 200 );
            $id=-28;
            $post = new stdClass();
            $post->ID= $id;
            $post->post_content='';
            $post->post_excerpt= '';
            $post->post_status='publish';
            $post->post_title= '';
            $post->post_type='post';
            $post->post_date = $yeararchive.'-'.$monthnumarchive.'-'.$dayarchive.'00:00:00';
            $wp_query->queried_object=$post;
            $wp_query->post=$post;
            $wp_query->found_posts = 1;
            $wp_query->post_count = 1;
            $wp_query->is_404 = false;
            $wp_query->posts = array($post);
            $wp_query->is_date = 1;
        }
    }
}add_filter('template_redirect', 'dg_override_404');
```

it work but doesn't show the page title in browser and if i changed

> $wp_query->is_date = 1;
>   to 
>   $wp_query->is_archive = 1;
>   work just fine but i need to use it in date page
>   so is there anyway to do that,thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the query with `pre_get_posts` before it's run to include `future` posts:

```
function wpd_future_date_archives( $query ){
    if( $query->is_date() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'future' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_future_date_archives' );
```

The posts won't behave the same as published posts though- they have no pretty permalink until they're published.

Comment: what i mean is the date page url redirect to 404 not display the future posts if i go to link like that http://localhost:8000/wordpress/2017/09/ the result is 404 page so i used the function in my question to force display the pages my issue is when using is_date the page doesn't display <title></title> but if used is_archive work just fine so i need soloution to do that with is_date

Comment: I understand your problem, and this solves that without having to use your code- it fixes the query *before* it's sent to the database so it never results in a 404.